# Manipular variáveis inexistentes no array

Tags: php, array

Como montar o seguinte array caso uma das variáveis não esteja definida?

`$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$d = 4;
$array = array($a, $b, $c, $d);`

Os valores das variáveis ($a, $b, $c e $d) provem de um servidor e muitas vezes elas não contém qualquer valor, logo o array se torna inconsistente.

Como solução, eu poderia utilizar o isset() para verificar se elas existem e caso não existissem, atribuir um valor qualquer. Mas, não posso atribuir novos valores caso elas não existam. Como proceder na montagem?

Caso uma delas não exista é retornado, como no código do exemplo em que falta a variável $c: `Undefined variable: c`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$array = array();

if(isset($a))
    $array[] = $a;

if(isset($b))
    $array[] = $b;

// . . .
```

Da maneira acima só serão adicionadas na array as variáveis que existirem.

Comment: Cahe, obrigado.

Comment: Desculpe, não vi que havia uma pergunta duplicada...

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do nossa amigo @Cahe é uma ótima solução. Mas eu gostaria de compartilhar aqui uma outra alternativa que, talvez, possa deixar o código um pouco mais simplificado.

É a função [compact()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.compact.php)

Segundo o Manual do PHP:

> Para cada um dos parâmetros passados, compact() procura uma variável
>   com o nome especificado na tabela de símbolos e a adiciona no array de
>   saída de forma que o nome da variável será a chave e o seu conteúdo
>   será o valor para esta chave.
>
> ... Qualquer string com nome de uma variável que não exista será
>   simplesmente ignorada.

É exatamente o que você precisa, de maneira mais simplificada.

Veja um exemplo:

```
<?php

    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    $d = 3;

    $array = compact('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

    print_r($array); // Array ( [a] => 1 [b] => 2 [d] => 3 )
```